# solution of system of equations having exponential and logarithmic functions

Tags: equation-solving

```
 Solve[{((-a + a E^(b Subscript[t, 1])) p + 
    2 a Subscript[c, p] + (-a - a E^(b Subscript[t, 1])) Subscript[c, 
     p] + 2 a Log[(1 + R - Subscript[t, 1])/(1 + R - T)] Subscript[c, 
     p] - i Subscript[c, 
     p] (-a Subscript[t, 1] + 
       a E^(b Subscript[t, 1]) Subscript[t, 1] - 
       a Log[(1 + R - Subscript[t, 1])/(1 + R - T)] Subscript[t, 1]))/
   T == 0, (
    a p + a Subscript[c, p] - (
     2 a Subscript[c, p] (1 + R - Subscript[t, 1]))/(1 + R - T) - 
     i Subscript[c, 
      p] (1/2 a (-1 - R + T + (1 + R - Subscript[t, 1])^2/(
           1 + R - T)) + (
        a (1 + R - Subscript[t, 1]) Subscript[t, 1])/(1 + R - T)))/
    T - 1/T^2 (-A - 
       2 a Log[(1 + R - Subscript[t, 1])/(1 + R - T)] Subscript[c, 
        p] (1 + R - Subscript[t, 1]) + 
       p (-((a (1 - E^(b Subscript[t, 1])))/b) + a T - 
          a Subscript[t, 1]) + 
       Subscript[c, 
        p] ((a (1 - E^(b Subscript[t, 1])))/b + a T - 
          a Subscript[t, 1]) - 
       i Subscript[c, 
        p] ((a (1 - E^(b Subscript[t, 1])))/b^2 + 
          1/2 a (1/2 (1 + R - T)^2 - 1/2 (1 + R - Subscript[t, 1])^2 +

             Log[(1 + R - Subscript[t, 1])/(
               1 + R - T)] (1 + R - Subscript[t, 1])^2) + (
          a E^(b Subscript[t, 1]) Subscript[t, 1])/b + 
          a Log[(1 + R - Subscript[t, 1])/(
            1 + R - T)] (1 + R - Subscript[t, 1]) Subscript[t, 1])) ==
    0}, {Subscript[t, 1], T}]
```

I want to solve above equations for t1, T by assigning values to all other variables.
Please help me.
Let me know about my mistake.

Comment: if you mean all other symbols have numeric values you should give values as an example. There is little chance of `Solve` working here, try `FindRoot`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SeedRandom[0];
```

Assign values to parameters

```
a = RandomReal[WorkingPrecision -> 20];
A = RandomReal[WorkingPrecision -> 20];
b = RandomReal[WorkingPrecision -> 20];
p = 1;
Subscript[c, p] = RandomReal[WorkingPrecision -> 20];
i = RandomReal[WorkingPrecision -> 20];
R = RandomReal[WorkingPrecision -> 20];

eqns = {
   ((-a + a E^(b Subscript[t, 1])) p + 
       2 a Subscript[c, p] + (-a - a E^(b Subscript[t, 1])) Subscript[c, p] + 
       2 a Log[(1 + R - Subscript[t, 1])/(1 + R - T)] Subscript[c, p] - 
       i Subscript[c, 
         p] (-a Subscript[t, 1] + a E^(b Subscript[t, 1]) Subscript[t, 1] - 
          a Log[(1 + R - Subscript[t, 1])/(1 + R - T)] Subscript[t, 1]))/T == 
    0,
   (a p + a Subscript[c, 
          p] - (2 a Subscript[c, p] (1 + R - Subscript[t, 1]))/(1 + R - T) - 
        i Subscript[c, 
          p] (1/2 a (-1 - R + 
              T + (1 + R - Subscript[t, 1])^2/(1 + R - T)) + (a (1 + R - 
                Subscript[t, 1]) Subscript[t, 1])/(1 + R - T)))/T - 
     1/T^2 (-A - 
        2 a Log[(1 + R - Subscript[t, 1])/(1 + R - T)] Subscript[c, 
          p] (1 + R - Subscript[t, 1]) + 
        p (-((a (1 - E^(b Subscript[t, 1])))/b) + a T - a Subscript[t, 1]) + 
        Subscript[c, 
          p] ((a (1 - E^(b Subscript[t, 1])))/b + a T - a Subscript[t, 1]) - 
        i Subscript[c, 
          p] ((a (1 - E^(b Subscript[t, 1])))/b^2 + 
           1/2 a (1/2 (1 + R - T)^2 - 1/2 (1 + R - Subscript[t, 1])^2 + 
              Log[(1 + R - Subscript[t, 1])/(1 + R - T)] (1 + R - 
                  Subscript[t, 1])^2) + (a E^(b Subscript[t, 1]) Subscript[t, 
               1])/b + a Log[(1 + R - Subscript[t, 1])/(1 + R - T)] (1 + R - 
              Subscript[t, 1]) Subscript[t, 1])) == 0};
```

As suggested by @george2079 use [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html)

```
sol = FindRoot[eqns, {{Subscript[t, 1], 1}, {T, 1}}, WorkingPrecision -> 15]

(* {Subscript[t, 1] -> 1.05141101097686, T -> 1.12612595142586} *)
```

Verifying the solution

```
And @@ (eqns /. sol)

(* True *)
```